# Why When I Pass Props Down to Child-Component it returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

In my App.Js file I'm attempting to have connection be establish to getting account, in App the passing the accountAddress(with returns a promise string) down to childComponenet {NavBar />}, so I can you that address and display it on the front-end.

But when I pass it down and consolelog the output. It keeps returning UNDEFINED? Any solutions or reason why this isn't working?

```
    import './App.css';
    import {Routes, Route,  BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
    import Home from './Home';
    import Nav from './Nav';
    import Gallery from './gallery
```

'

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import {Contract, providers, Provier, utilis} from 'ethers';
import Web3Modal from 'web3modal';
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
export default function App() { 
  const [walletConnected,setWalletConnected] = useState(false); 
  //loading is set to TRUE when waiting for transaction to get Minted 
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false); 
  const [isOwner, setIsOwner] = useState(false); 
  //tokenIDMinted keeps track of the number of tokenIDS that have been minted
  const [tokenIdsMinted, setTokenIdsMinted] = useState("0");
  const [accountAdress, setAccountAddress] = useState();
  //Create a reference to the Web3Modal (used for Connecting to Metamask) which persist as long as page is open
  const web3ModalRef = useRef();


  const getProviderOrSigner = async (needSigner = false) => {
    // Connect to Metamask
    // Since we store `web3Modal` as a reference, we need to access the `current` value to get access to the underlying object
    const provider = await web3ModalRef.current.connect();
    const web3Provider = new providers.Web3Provider(provider);
    const signer = web3Provider.getSigner();
    const address = await signer.getAddress(); 
    setAccountAddress(address);
    console.log(accountAdress);
    console.log("Connected")
  
    // If user is not connected to the Rinkeby network, let them know and throw an error
    const { chainId } = await web3Provider.getNetwork();
    if (chainId !== 4) {
      window.alert("Change the network to Rinkeby");
      throw new Error("Change network to Rinkeby");
    }
  
    if (needSigner) {
      const signer = web3Provider.getSigner();
   
      return signer;
    }
    return web3Provider;
  };
    const connectWallet = async() => { 
      try { 
        //Get Provider from web3moal
        //When used for the first time, it prompts user to connect their wallet
        await getProviderOrSigner();
        
        setWalletConnected(true);
      }catch(err) { 
        console.error(err)
      }
    };
    
 
  
    useEffect(() => { 
  
  if(!walletConnected) {
    //Assign web3modal class to reference object by setting its' current value
    //The current value is persisted throughout as long as this page is open
    web3ModalRef.current = new Web3Modal({
      network: 'rinkeby',
      providerOptions: {},
      disableInjectedProvider: false,

    })
    connectWallet()
  }


}, [walletConnected])




return (
  <div>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Nav
    setAccountAddress = {setAccountAddress}
    setWalletConnected = {setWalletConnected}
    getProviderOrSigner = {getProviderOrSigner}
    connectWallet = {connectWallet}
    web3ModalRef = {web3ModalRef}
    accountAdress = {accountAdress}
    />
```

"NAV JS FILE" -> In this file I pass down the Props, though it still console.logs Undefined

```
import './App.css';
import ConnectWallet from './ConnectWallet';
import {  Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import {Contract, providers, Provier, utilis} from 'ethers';
import Web3Modal from 'web3modal';
import { ethers } from 'ethers';



export default function Nav(account,  connectWallet,web3ModalRef, getProviderOrSigner,walletConnected,wallet,accountAdress ) { 
//setState for ScrollDown 
const scrollToBottom = () => {
  window.scrollTo({
    top: 9000,
    behavior: "smooth",
  })

}
 

console.log(parseInt(accountAdress))
  const renderButton = () => { 
    if(!walletConnected) { 
      return ( 
        
        <nav className = "nav">
            <ul className = "navUl">
                <li>
                <Link className = "link" to = "/">Home</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                <Link className = "link" to = "/about">About Artist</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                <Link  className = "link" to = "/gallery">Art Gallery</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a  onClick={scrollToBottom} >Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div onClick={connectWallet} className = "btn">
            Connect Wallet
        </div>
        </nav>
      )
    }
  }





    return (

        <nav className = "nav">
            <ul className = "navUl">
                <li>
                <Link className = "link" to = "/">Home</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                <Link className = "link" to = "/about">About Artist</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                <Link  className = "link" to = "/gallery">Art Gallery</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a  onClick={scrollToBottom} >Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div className = "btnAddress ">
            <p>
              {accountAdress}
            </p>
        </div>
        </nav>


    )




}
```

Comment: It will be initially undefined. Only render nav after setting `accountAdress` or handle undefined in the Nav component.

Comment: Okay, how would that be displayed in code? for the rendering after/ or how could I handle the undefined in the nav component?